# How to convert the data retrieved by GraphQL + Relay to normal React state?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

[Example from the documentation](https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/use-preloaded-query/):

```
import type {AppQueryType} from 'AppQueryType.graphql';

const React = require('React');

const {graphql, useQueryLoader, usePreloadedQuery} = require('react-relay');

const AppQuery = graphql`
  query AppQuery($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      name
    }
  }
`;

type Props = {
  initialQueryRef: PreloadedQuery<AppQueryType>,
};

function NameLoader(props) {
  const [queryReference, loadQuery] = useQueryLoader(
    AppQuery,
    props.initialQueryRef, /* e.g. provided by router */
  );

  return (<>
    <Button
      onClick={() => loadQuery({id: '4'})}
      disabled={queryReference != null}
    >
      Reveal your name!
    </Button>
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      {queryReference != null
        ? <NameDisplay queryReference={queryReference} />
        : null
      }
    </Suspense>
  </>);
}

function NameDisplay({ queryReference }) {
  const data = usePreloadedQuery(AppQuery, queryReference);

  return <h1>{data.user?.name}</h1>;
}
```

Too complicated. First, I don't want to split the initial component to `NameLoader` and `NameDisplay` only because it is convenient for the Relay. Second, even I have the child component, I don't want the `PreloadedQuery` be among `props` because it is the tight copulation of the Relay and the simple React component (it means the replacing of the Relay with something else will entail the editing of all components such `NameDisplay`). Instead I want to pass the normal data via `props`, such the `user` object.

The desired code will be like:

```
import type {AppQueryType} from 'AppQueryType.graphql';

const React = require('React');

const {graphql, useQueryLoader, usePreloadedQuery} = require('react-relay');

const AppQuery = graphql`
  query AppQuery($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      name
    }
  }
`;


function NameLoader(props) {
  const rawUser = useMagic(AppQuery);
  const [ user, setUser ] = toLocalState(rawUser);

  return (<>
    <Button
      onClick={() => loadQuery({id: '4'})}
      disabled={queryReference != null}
    >
      Reveal your name!
    </Button>
    <h1>{user.name}</h1>;
  </>);
}
```

I understand that the data fetching is the asynchronous but it sould not mean that what Realy suggesting in the only correct solution.

From the `const [ user, setUser ] = toLocalState(rawUser);` line, I want to work with the `user` variable as with normal local state. In this example, I don't care that local changes with `user` will not reflect on `user` at server side - when I'll be ready for reflecting, I'll invoke the appropriate mutation.

What will be instead of `useMagic` and `toLocalState`?

Comment: based on the docs, it seems like u would need to anyways extract the name portion to a different component for u to use the preloaded query, but u could opt to use the `useLazyLoadQuery` which returns the data directly

Answer (score 0):

The code addresses the original concerns as follows:

Avoiding Component Splitting: The code keeps the component as a single unit (App) rather than splitting it into multiple components, simplifying the code structure.

Passing User Data as a Prop: It passes the user data as a prop (user) to the component, making it easier to work with and avoiding tight coupling with Relay-specific functionality.

Fetching Data on Component Mount: It uses the useEffect hook to fetch data when the component mounts, ensuring that the data is available before rendering and reducing the delay in displaying new entries when redirected.

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import {
  graphql,
  usePreloadedQuery
} from 'react-relay';

const AppQuery = graphql `
  query AppQuery($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      name
    }
  }
`;

function App(props) {
  const {
    initialQueryRef
  } = props;
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const data = usePreloadedQuery(AppQuery, initialQueryRef);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch user data
    const fetchData = async() => {
      try {
        const response = await loadQuery({
          id: '4'
        });
        setUser(response.user);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors
      }
    };

    // Fetch data when component mounts
    fetchData();
  }, [initialQueryRef]);

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    h1 > User Name: {
      user ? .name
    } < /h1> <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```